# Clicks going through <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have the following `<span>` element:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash icon" ></span>
```

which has `display:block;z-index:100;` and a parent who has a `click` event and `z-index:0;`.

The `<span>` also has a `click` event. For some reason clicks on the `<span>` executes the parents `click` event instead of the span's. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to stop events from bubbling:

```
$(".ui-icon-trash").click( function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```